# Singleton initializing twice, std::call_once also running twice

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I have following simple singleton, the std::call_once is just to make sure that things are broken, I intend to remove it as soon as I have this working.

```
std::once_flag flag1;

ProfileModel* ProfileModel::instance()
{
    std::call_once(flag1, [](){ qDebug() << "Simple example: called once\n"; });
    static ProfileModel self;
    qDebug() << &self ;
    return &self;
}
```

Looks simple, and from what I know from C++ this should work. but I'm having two pointers returned by this call, and `call once` also prints twice.

```
Simple example: called once
Constructing Konsole::ProfileModel(0x7ff7378a31f0)
Simple example: called once
Constructing Konsole::ProfileModel(0x5592aeb87160)
```

The only thing I did that I'm not sure it matters, is that I have this inside of a static library, and I only call this twice, once inside of this library, once outside - in the main application.

Anyone can share a bit of light?

Comment: It's only defined once, right? It's only defined in the library, not also in the application?

Comment: I don't see `qDebug() << &self` in the output. The output doesn't look like it was generated by the code shown.

Comment: just put a breakpoint in ProfileModel::ProfileModel and see where it is called

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the output was manually written, the original call was qDebug() "Constructing" << &self; I'll edit.

Comment: @Jeffrey I did, it's being called twice but shouldn't. I think this is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547454/static-variable-is-initialized-twice .

Answer (score 1):

It's a duplicate of [Static variable is initialized twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547454/static-variable-is-initialized-twice) , with the difference that here it's not a static variable, but a method that has a static variable.