# C global static variable initialization is done by linker?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, symbol-table

Let's say we have:

f1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int x = 10;

void f1() {
  printf("f1.c : %d\n", x);
}
```

main.c

```
extern void f1();
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  f1();
  return 0;
}
```

we will compile and read the two ELF file symboltables (rel. ELF and exec ELF):

```
$> gcc -c *.c
$> readelf -s f1.o | grep x
      Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
        5: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 x
$> gcc *.o
$> readelf -s a.out | grep x
      Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
       38: 0000000000601038     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   25 x
```

I can see that the `Value` (also known as address) in which the global static variable `x` is `0000000000000000` from reading the relocatable object file `f1.o`.
Which means we haven't initialized it yet since it is still a rel. ELF object file and the linker will take care of this.

So my question is then, if the linker is the one to set `x` to the value of 10 at known address after linking of `0000000000601038`, how does it do so?  Where does the linker get the information to ***set the value to 10*** and who gives this information (`f1.o`?) ?

Comment: The Value here is the *address* of the variable `x`, not the value of `x`

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yes, I've noted that in the initial question already which wasn't a confusion, I see how it can sound like I meant it wasn't initialized because of that though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value `0000000000000000` (in object file `f1.o`) is a *relative* address (of the static variable), so is an offset, and that file also contains [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) directives related to it. The code for getting the argument `x` to print has also some relocation on it (on some load machine instruction).

In that object file you probably have a `.data` section. That section should start with a word  (having the 0 offset you observed in `f1.o`) containing 10.

Read much more about [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) (I recommend Levine's [*Linkers and loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/) book).  The linking process (to get the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable) is processing relocation directives. Read also more about the ELF format, starting with [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) (after having read the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) wikipage). Study also the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specifications (for Linux x86-64 see [here](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348010/841108) answer) which details possible relocation directives.

You may want to compile your `f1.c` with `gcc -Wall -S -fverbose-asm -O1 f1.c` then look at the emitted assembler file `f1.s`

You may also want to inspect the object file `f1.o` and the ELF executable `a.out` with various tools like [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) and [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html). Both accept numerous options (notably the `-r` option to `objdump` to show relocation directives).

[Dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) `libc.*.so`) introduces some additional complexity in the ELF executable. See also [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) (which does some linking job at start of runtime) and [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html). You may also want to read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper.

The freely available textbook [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) could also be worthwhile to read (it explains what a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) is and how its execution proceeds).

Answer (score 3):

This segment where static storage duration variables with specific values are stored, is known as `.data` (this is the name used by the ELF standard but other linkers tend to use the very same name too).

How these variables are set depend on the target system.

- On RAM-based systems (such as a PC), the whole `.data` segment is initialized in advance as part of the executable and loaded to RAM together with the program.
- On ROM-based systems (such as microcontrollers with flash), `.data` cannot be initialized in advance. Instead it is copied down from ROM to RAM before main() is called, by some start-up code ("CRT"). So it is actually set in run-time, meaning that there's always a delay at program start on such systems. To get rid of the delay, there's often a non-standard start-up alternative ("minimal") which skips initialization of static storage duration variables entirely.